# Bundle node_modules using Bundler & Minifier extension

Tags: bundle, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, node-modules

I want to bundle my node_modules using the Bundler & Minifier extension.

This is my bundleconfig.json

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "someLocation/**/*.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/bundle.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "someLocation/**/*.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/vendor.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/**/*.js",
      "!node_modules/**/*.min.js",
      "!node_modules/**/*.umd.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

My idea here is to include all js files in the node_modules folder and exclude all the minified or bundled ones.

The problem is that I am getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** exception in the vendor.js file, after bundling.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a proper way of bundling the node_modules folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you handle it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I just moved to webpack. :)